# Eclipse formatter: How to move comment between method name and open brace to always have open brace on same line as method declaration

Tags: eclipse, formatting, ide, eclipse-formatter

I have code that looks like this, that I'm trying to format

Original code:

```
public int doThing(int a) // -incredibly useful comment here
{
    int ab = a+1;

    return ab;
}
```

I want it to look like this

```
public int doThing(int a) { // -incredibly useful comment here
    int ab = a+1;

    return ab;
}
```

If I try to turn on the Brace position -> Method Declaration -> Same line option and run the formatter, any code with a comment in the position "breaks" the formatter, and I get an output for my example that looks the same as the original code, but methods without a comment have the correct formatting (meaning the results are inconsistent).

Is it possible with the eclipse formatter to get the style I want? I'm trying to run it against a large amount of code, and would prefer not to have to fix these all manually to get a consistent brace position.

Comment: The problem here is that is not formatting but rewriting. Using  File Search + regular expression + Replace could do that in bulk.

Comment: It would be something like this. Formatting changes whitespace, and only the whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that is not formatting but rewriting. Using File Search + regular expression + Replace could do that in bulk.

Try this regex

```
^(\s*(?:public|private|protected)\s+[^(]+\([^)]*\))(\s*\/\/[^/]+)\R\s*\{
```

On File Search ( Ctrl + H)

[image: File search box]

Hit `Replace` and use `$1 { $2\n` as replacement

[image: Replace box]

Code should compile after the refactoring.

UPDATE:
Fixed regex part that represents function arguments

`\([^)]*\)`

Full Regex matches these cases

```
public int doSmthg() // coment here
{
    return 1;
}

private String doSmthgElse(String arg) // coment here
    {
    return arg;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I posted this question as an Eclipse one, but I'm actually using VS Code (I was just using Eclipse to generate the eclipse-formatter.xml)

I was able to edit your regex to work there (VS Code uses the Rust regex engine which has slightly different rules, particularly around escaping characters), though due to my lack of experience with regex, I switched the \R towards the end to \n, since it was coming up as invalid in the parser (I know the code I'm working with is all LF)

```^(\s*(?:public|private|protected)\s+[^(]+\([^)]*\))(\s*//[^/]+)\n\s*\{```

Comment: It's a Perl extension t seems `\R Any Unicode linebreak sequence \u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html